# Where can I find an English translation of Pan Pingge Searching for Humanity (求仁录)?

Tags: chinese-language, pan-pingge

I'm interested in reading works by the Chinese philosopher Pan Pingge. His work entitled *Searching for Humanity* or 求仁录 appears, from secondary sources, to be a good place to start. However, I cannot track down any English translations of works by him. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I searched WorldCat and the catalogues of the Library of Congress and the British Library without success :-(